# Passing group by condition as parameter using Func

Tags: c#, delegates, func

I have a class and method like below

```
public class Product{

public int Id{get;set;}
public string Name{get;set;}
}

private void Method(List<Product> products)
{

 var grouped = products.GroupBy(x=>x.ProductId)

 ....etc

}
```

Is it possible to pass the group by condition x=>x.ProductId as parameter? because sometimes i want to group by Name, Id...etc

Please can some one help? I tried to implement Func Deletegate, but I am facing a problem with datatype mismatch

```
private void Method(List<Product> products, Func<Product, long> groupByCond)
    {

     var grouped = products.GroupBy(groupByCond)

     ....etc

    }
```

but for grouping by Name, instead of long it expects type string. Could some one help to make this generic such that it accepts all types?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do as you would do for any other generic method, use a generic type parameter (e.g., `TProperty`) instead of `long`.

```
private void Method<TProperty>(List<Product> products, Func<Product, TProperty> groupByCond)
```

Comment: Thanks, never thought it would be this easy :)